# Same git project, two local servers, HTTP 404 for all prod env sites only in one server using clone git and same deploying steps (symfony2)

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, symfony

One git project cloned and deployed using **same steps** (f.e. composer install command) on **two machines** (both local servers, with WAMP), with project empty  cache, results in **HTTP 404** for **prod env** sites in server1 and works properly on server2.

- Development env works properly in both servers.
- Same Apache httpd.conf in both server1 and server2.
- Same .htaccess in public directory in both projects.

Server1:

```
.../web -works
.../web/app_dev.php/ -works

.../web/app_dev.php/book -works
.../web/book - 404

.../web/app_dev.php/new -works
.../web/new - 404
```

debug:route on Server1:

```
Name                                Method   Scheme Host Path
index                               ANY      ANY    ANY  /
book                                ANY      ANY    ANY  /book
new                                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /new
```

.htaccess in web/ symfony2 public dir

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]    
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you run - `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup`

Comment: "Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false" but cache are clear anyway.

Comment: You declared the route as `/new` but ask for `/new/`, can you try without en ending slash?

Comment: @A.L.  same without slash

Comment: Does `.../web/app.php/new` work? It looks like the URL rewriting which should call silently `app.php/` fails.

Comment: @A.L It's work with /app.php/ ! Do yoo know what it mean, and how to change it? (If you dont know and if you want I can accept above as an anwer.)

Comment: You mentioned `httpd.conf`, do you use Apache or Apache2? Anyway you have to find an `.htaccess` (I'm pretty sure the syntax is the same than in the configuration files) that work with your server in order to remove `app.php/`. You can try the one from [symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/web/.htaccess).